# Reading and write XML content using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am currently reading XML Content from a file using Get-Content and powershell. Then, I make that content as an xml object and make some modifications on the dates. 
I am now trying to write the XML Modified content back the original file using Set-Content; However, it only writes the following: "System.Xml.XmlDocument" 
Could someone please suggest a better way to write XML Content to the file? Below is the Powershell code I am using:

```
    $xmlExample = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\ELO1MTP\Documents\RPAVERTEX\TaxDataExportRequestSample.xml

#convert example to xml object
[xml]$xml = $xmlExample

#Change Start / End to today
$xml.Envelope.Body.RunTaxDataExportRequest.StartDate = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$xml.Envelope.Body.RunTaxDataExportRequest.EndDate = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

#Write Results to original file
set-Content -Path C:\Users\ELO1MTP\Documents\RPAVERTEX\TaxDataExportRequestSample.xml -Value $xml
$xml.Envelope.Body.RunTaxDataExportRequest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to convert XML back to the string format, this should work for you.

`$xml.OuterXml`

Now you can write it back to the disk like:

```
set-Content -Path C:\Users\ELO1MTP\Documents\RPAVERTEX\TaxDataExportRequestSample.xml -Value $xml.OuterXml
```

Answer (score 0):

Makes it pretty too.  If there's an encoding attribute at the top, it will guide the encoding it will save as.

```
$xml.save('C:\Users\ELO1MTP\Documents\RPAVERTEX\TaxDataExportRequestSample.xml')
```